# How to open app from last opened activity even after its removed from recent task

Tags: android

My app has two activity one is sign in and second is main,I login from sign in activity and then I go to main activity, but when I remove my app from recent tasks and reopen it, it reopens from the sign in activity.

How to make it so that it reopens from the last closed activity i.e main in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

After you have Logged In, [Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) a [shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to save that action and on the launcher activity just check the value stored for the same shared preference to check if you had logged in successfully last time or not.